# Is there a way to send VRFY command + username to netcat from bash script?

Tags: bash, netcat

Im writing a bash script which receives an IP and a user as arguments in order to know if that user exists remotely using netcat with the VRFY command after the connection was stablished, but my code doesn't works. How can I send the user argument to netcat? Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=$1
usr=$2
nc -nvv $dest 25
VRFY $usr
```

Usage: sh users.sh 192.168.26.140 bin

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the command into netcat's stdin:

```
nc -nvv "$dest" 25 <<< "VRFY $usr"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and I solved in the form:

```
#!/bin/bash
dest=$1
usr=$2
echo "VRFY $usr" | nc -q 1 -n $dest 25
```

Also with the option -q to finalize netcat after the verify command